# Python OOP override

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I am dealing some problems with inheritance that I do not know what is the best way to do it. There is a class `Base` that when initialize the class, the method `_load_data` loads `Data` objects in a array. How `Data` objects does not have all information that I need, I create a subclass `ExtBase` that overrides `_load_data` loading `DataExtended` objects. The problem of this approach is that linters does not like to much. What is the best way to implement `ExtBase` and property `data_list` that returns `DataExtended` objects in python?

```
import dataclasses
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from typing import List


@dataclasses.dataclass
class Data:
    name: str
    nice: bool


@dataclasses.dataclass
class DataExtended(Data):
    ok: bool


class BaseInterface(metaclass=ABCMeta):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def data_list(self) -> List[Data]:
        """Property"""


class ExtBaseInterface(BaseInterface, metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def data_list(self) -> DataExtended:
        """Ext Property"""


class Base(BaseInterface):
    _IS_BASE = True

    def __init__(self, name: str):
        self._data: List[Data] = []
        self._load_data(name)

    @property
    def data_list(self) -> List[Data]:
        return self._data

    def _load_data(self, name):
        self._data.append(Data(name, self._IS_BASE))


class ExtBase(ExtBaseInterface, Base):
    # def __init__(self, name: str):
    #     super().__init__(name)

    # def _load_data(self, name):
    #     self._data.append(DataExtended(name, self._IS_BASE, False))
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but you haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sorry I redo de "question". Sorry.